# Formula for greatest cross section of regular dodecahedron

Tags: geometry, area, polyhedra, platonic-solids

Is there a formula for the area of greatest cross section of a regular dodecahedron?

For example, this can be viewed as finding a hole big enough for it to fit into.

Comment: Here's something to think about:  how do you **know** that the greatest cross sectional area occurs for a plane perpendicular to a fivefold axis of symmetry?  Is it possible that the maximal such area occurs for some other plane through the center of the dodecahedron?

Comment: I don't care where the cross sectional area IS, I want to know how to calculate it so that I can make a hole the big enough for the dodecahedron to fit into as good as possible. Like one of those toddler toys where you push pegs through holes. Only with a dodecahedron.

Comment: I see.  In that case, you might want to rephrase your question to be more specific about this.  You should also be aware that the diagram you included shows a blue decagon as a cross section.  If you were to cut a hole of that shape and size, the dodecahedron still wouldn't pass through.

Comment: Right. How would I calculate this then? Area of the top-down orthographic projection?

Comment: Has the diagram showing blue decagon been removed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will furnish an answer based on the assumption that the dodecahedron is intended to pass through a hole which is in a plane perpendicular to a fivefold axis.  If you were to rotate the dodecahedron to a different orientation (e.g., along a threefold or twofold axis), the shape of the hole would not only be different, its area may actually be *smaller*.

With this in mind, the cross-section's shape is obviously a regular decagon.  Some elaborate computation shows that, if the dodecahedron has an edge length of $1$, then the side length of the smallest such decagonal hole is $$\sqrt{\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{10}} \approx 0.850651.$$  The area of this hole is $$\sqrt{\frac{5(25+11\sqrt{5})}{8}} \approx 5.56758.$$

Comment: And how would I scale this formula up? For example, if the edge length was 5, the area would be about 27.8379?

Comment: The area will scale as the **square** of the edge length of the dodecahedron.  So if the edge length is $5$ units, the area will increase by a factor of $25$, not $5$.

Comment: Thank-you heaps for your easy to understand assistance.